# Excel - Convert String to a formula

Tags: string, excel, formula, evaluate

I have a formula that is generated via a series of concatenated strings. This is better explained with an example:

open a new Excel workbook

```
 A1 = 5

 C1 = 5 & "+A1" [A1 is seen as text. C1 will contain "5+A1" ]
```

I would like E1 to contain the result of C1 evaluated as a formula, so basically in this example 10.

I tried to use `INDIRECT(C1)` but it did not work.

UPDATE: It must work with Custom cell names. so if for example i assign the name "mycell" to A1, then the field C1 will contain "5+mycell"

UPDATE 2: my real data:

sheet 1, cell Y20 contains this:

```
-0,0000014369849267*Drehzahl^2 + 0,0401449351560780*Drehzahl - 32,5068828005099000
```

sheet 2, cell J7 contains this:

```
= 'Sheet 1'!Y20
```

sheet 2, cell J8 contains this:

```
= eval(J7)
```

sheet 2, cell C7 is renamed as Drezahl

Update 3: a formula that is not working for me:

it requires 4 custom renamed cells: "Drezahl" (value=3550) Kondtemp (45) Saugtemp (-45) Schlitten(100) the result of the calc must be about 91,17

```
((((-0,0000014369849267*Drehzahl^2 + 0,0401449351560780*Drehzahl - 32,5068828005099000) + ((8,95609756097562+(18,1/2050)*Drehzahl))*(1/25)*(45-Kondtemp))*((0,0000262088992942*Saugtemp^3 + 0,0050210402289170*Saugtemp^2 + 0,3711985619535020*Saugtemp + 9,9227907759641600)*((0,361075074412964)*(3550/Drehzahl)-0,361075074412964+1))*((((100-50)/(91,4-46,3))*((0,014285714285714*Schlitten^2 - 1,262285714285720*Schlitten + 74,214285714286400)-46,3)+50)-50))/50)+((0,0000063790283394*Drehzahl^2 - 0,0103039106823734*Drehzahl + 2,6771661029208000)*(-0,0002159827213823*Kondtemp^2 - 0,0034865782165998*Kondtemp + 1,5954952175254600))*(((0,000000003885345*Saugtemp^6 + 0,000000666998414*Saugtemp^5 + 0,000042907134551*Saugtemp^4 + 0,001268740583850*Saugtemp^3 + 0,020179866978636*Saugtemp^2 + 0,418860651690801*Saugtemp + 9,465861006018070)*((((7,68293017999336)/(-2050)*(Drehzahl-3550)+1)-1)/(45)*(Saugtemp+45)+1)))*(1/-50*((((100-50)/(91,4-46,3))*((0,014285714285714*Schlitten^2 - 1,262285714285720*Schlitten + 74,214285714286400)-46,3)+50)-100))`
```

Comment: Is there any reason why you're storing `5+A1` in C1 as TEXT? Where does the first `5` come from? Is it in `B` col by any chance?

Comment: yes, this is only an example.. in my file the text is generated from various sources that are entered as text. the first 5 is just a random number..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add very simple user defined function to your workbook:

```
Function eval(str As String)
    Application.Volatile
    eval = Evaluate(Evaluate(Replace(str, ",", ".")))
End Function
```

and call it in `E1` like this: `=eval(C1)`

**Notes:**

1) I've used double `Evaluate` for the case when data in `C1` stores like text without `=` sign : `5 & "A1"`. If your data stored with `=` sign: `=5 & "A1"`, you can use `eval = Evaluate(str)` or leave `eval = Evaluate(Evaluate(str))` - it doesen't metter

2) since VBA needs `.` as delimeter , I've used `Replace` function

**NEW UPDATE:**

But, `Evaluate` can operate only with strings less or equal 255 characters..
In that case you can use following UDF:

```
Public app As Excel.Application
Public wb As Workbook

Function getValue(formulaString As String)
    Application.Volatile
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    'set default falue to #REF..if we'd get normal value - we'll change getValue to it'
    getValue = CVErr(xlErrRef)

    getValue = Evaluate(Evaluate(Replace(formulaString, ",", ".")))
    If Not IsError(getValue) Then
    Exit Function
    End If

    'if we appear here - second WB is closed...'
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    If app Is Nothing Then Set app = New Excel.Application
    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = app.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.FullName)
    With wb.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name)
        With .Range(Application.ThisCell.Address)
            .FormulaLocal = IIf(Left(formulaString, 1) <> "=", "=" & formulaString, formulaString)
            .Calculate
            getValue = .Value
        End With
    End With

ErrHandler:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Function
```

and last thing: add following code to the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
   If Not wb Is Nothing Then wb.Close False
   If Not app Is Nothing Then app.Quit
   Set app = Nothing
   Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: it partially works.. works fine as long as i write "A1" in the formula, but stops working if i use assigned cellnames. Updating my post

Comment: hm..it works for me..I've gave `test` name for `A1` and wrote in `C1` folloring formula: `=5 & "+test"`.

Comment: I understand! You should write `=` before the text

Comment: It doesnt seem to work because in my real Excel table i am taking my "A1" field from another worksheet. so instead of "A1" i have 'sheet2'!A1.. might that be the reason? updating the main post with my real data.

Comment: how can i troubleshoot what the problem is if a specific formula does not work? for instance, how did you find out about the , and the . in my formula? thanks!

Comment: @sharkyenergy, It's experience:) I've many troubleshoots with local settings before) Have you some problem with your formula?

Comment: yep i have a very long formula that is failing. but the formula itself is correct as it is calculated correctly if i put a "=" in front of it and let Excel calc it.. the formula is to long to share here so i have to post it in the main question

Comment: `Evaluate` can get string with length less or equal 255..http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193019(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: it keeps opening hundreds of Excel instances until the pc crashes! any idea why?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45283/discussion-between-sharkyenergy-and-simoco)

Answer (score 0):

I have almost the exact issue, except mine aren't named cells and its less than 255 chars. going to try the

```
Function eval(str As String)
    Application.Volatile
    eval = Evaluate(Evaluate(Replace(str, ",", ".")))
End Function
```